# Requesting memory more than available

Tags: memory-management, dynamic, virtual-memory

Suppose there is 50 MB to allocate and there is this for loop which allocates memory in each iteration. What happens when the following for loop runs.

for(int i=0; i < 20; i++)
{

```
int *p = malloc(5MB);
```

}

I was asked this question in an interview. Can someone guide me on this and direct me to the necessary topics which I must learn in order to understand such situations.

Comment: Does the 50MB refer to physical memory, or the available address space? (Assuming this is on a system with virtual memory.) Interview questions don't necessarily have simple answers like that.

Comment: @millimoose: Thanks for your reply. I am sorry I did not mention that this 50 MB refers to physical memory. And also the system has virtual memory. I did refer to virtual memory in my answer that virtual memory will handle the excess memory allocation. The interviewer told was satisfied but wanted me to explain in detail. Can you please show me some further pointers to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a system utilising virtual memory then the situation is obviously more complex than malloc simply failing and returning null pointers. In this case the malloc call will result in allocation of pages of memory in the virtual address space. When this memory is accessed a page fault will result, control will be given to the os memory manager, and this will map the virtual memory pages to pages of physical memory. When the physical memory available is full then the memory manager will generally handle further page faults by writing data which is currently in physical memory into disk backing (or simply discarding this data if it is already backed by a disk file), and then remapping this now available physical memory for the virtual memory page which originally resulted in the page fault. Any attempts to access virtual address pages which have previously been written out to disk backing will result in a similar process occurring.

Wikipedia contains a reasonably basic overview of this process (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging), including some implementation details for different os's. More detailed information is available from a number of other sources, eg. the intel architectures software development manuals (http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation for malloc (eg. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) you will get a pointer to a memory block of 5MB (noting that the argument for malloc should be the number of bytes required, not MB..) the first 10 times (maybe 9 times if there is overhead associated with the malloc'ed space which is taken out of the 50MB available), and a pointer to this space will be returned. Following this further 5MB chunks of memory will not be available, and malloc will fail, returning a null pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I mentioned 5MB in malloc just to make calculation easy.